# Existence of certain homogenous forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, elliptic-curves

Let $D(X,Y), E(X,Y)\in\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ forms of the same degree $n$ and suppose  that the resultant $R=Res(D,E)$ of $D$ and $E$ is not $0$.

Show that there are homogenous forms $L_0(X,Y),M_0(X,Y), L_1(X,Y),M_1(X,Y)\in\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ with

$$L_0D+M_0E=R\cdot X^{2n-1}$$
and 
$$L_1D+M_1E=R\cdot Y^{2n-1}$$

I encountered this problem while preparing a talk about the proof of the Mordell-Weil theorem for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ and don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you taking the resultant to be the ordinary Sylvester resultant of $D(x,1)$ and $E(x,1)$, so it's just a rational number? If so, then its appearance on the right side of the displayed equations is superfluous, since you could use $L_0'=L_0/R$, and so on, right?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I realized that since I want to say something about the height of the quotient $D/E$, it's necessary to normalize both polynomials and actually find forms with integer coefficients. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Wikipedia article on resultant says, If P and Q are two polynomials over a commutative ring R, then there exist two polynomials A and B in the variable X over R such that AP + BQ = res(P, Q) (with the right hand side being interpreted as a constant polynomial). They are talking about polynomials in one variable, but maybe that's the same thing as forms of equal degree in two variables.

Comment: See also Proposition 5 of http://math.rice.edu/~cbruun/vigre/vigreHW9.pdf

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of getting an ordinary polynomial by setting $Y=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D(x)$ and $E(x)$ are polynomials of degree $n$ with coefficients in a commutative ring, then it is a standard property of resultants that there are polynomials $L$ and $M$ of degree $n-1$ such that $$L(x)D(x)+M(x)E(x)=R$$ where $R$ is the resultant of $D$ and $E$.

Given forms $D(x,y)$ and $E(x,y)$, we get $$L(x)D(x,1)+M(x)E(x,1)=R$$ then we let $x=X/Y$ and multiply by $Y^{2n-1}$ to get $$L_1(X,Y)D(X,Y)+M_1(X,Y)E(X,Y)=RY^{2n-1}$$ and we do the same with $D(1,y)$ and $E(1,y)$ to get the other equation you want.